# Setting ContextPath in Struts2 Action Class gives wrong path

Tags: servlets, struts2, contextpath

I'm currently trying to set a context path for a config file in my webapp, but it seems no matter what solution I try, none of them give the right path. The config file is found in WEB-INF/Config.

I've tried using `ServletContextAware` in order to grab the context path, but it seems to give me the wrong path.

> C:\Documents and Settings\Person\My
>   Documents\geronimo-tomcat6-javaee5-2.2-bin\geronimo-tomcat6-javaee5-2.2\bin\org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade@5d869c\WEB-INF\config\config.xml

```
private ServletContext context;
public void setServletContext(ServletContext context) {
    this.context = context;
}
AdminFile = builder.parse(context + "/WEB-INF/config/config.xml");
```

I've also tried creating a context path through org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext, by calling ServletActionContext.getServletContext, but that gives me a similar error.

> C:\Documents and Settings\Person\My
>   Documents\geronimo-tomcat6-javaee5-2.2-bin\geronimo-tomcat6-javaee5-2.2\bin\org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade@156592a\WEB-INF\config\config.xml

```
ServletContext context = ServletActionContext.getServletContext();
AdminFile = builder.parse(context + "/WEB-INF/config/config.xml");
```

I finally tried using ServletRequestAware, and it gave me better results, but still not the full context path I need. I would also like to avoid coupling my action class to the servlet api.

> \JSPPrototype\WEB-INF\config\config.xml

```
public HttpServletRequest request;
public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) 
{
this.request = request;  
}

String context = request.getContextPath();
AdminFile = builder.parse(context + "/WEB-INF/config/config.xml");
```

What exactly am I doing wrong, and how should I build a ContextPath that works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ServletContext` is not the same as the context path of your application. The `ServletContext` is an object that your web application can use to interface with the servlet container. Hence, what you're doing with your approach is to concatenate that object with a `String`, which invokes it's `toString()` method, which just prints the implementing class name and it's hashcode. Which obviously does not match your path.

What you instead need to do is to use the `ServletContext` to get a `URL` to your file. And to do that, you actually use the `ServletContext`. You can get the `URL` of a file in your web application with the [`getResource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) method of the `ServletContext`. Something like this:

```
builder.parse(context.getResource('/WEB-INF/config/config.xml'));
```

This requires your `parse` method to accept a `URL` object. You can also use `getResourceAsStream()`, if your builder accepts a parameter of type `InputStream` instead.

Comment: Whoa, I can't believe I missed that. Thanks so much for the help, it works perfectly!